# jquery mobile radio buttons onclick event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile radio buttons with onclick event ,onclick event is not fired on  first click it fires on second click i.e double click is working 
how can i solve it

**Code**

```
<div class="radio" data-role="fieldcontain" id="divDays"> 
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> 
     <label for="5day" name="dayview0" onclick="loadProjectMainBody()" class="text13"> 
        <input type="radio" name="days" id="5day" value="5" checked="checked" /> 5 DAY VIEW   
     </label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="radio" data-role="fieldcontain" id="divDays">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="5day" name="dayview0" onclick="loadProjectMainBody()" class="text13">
                            <input type="radio" name="days" id="5day" value="5" checked="checked" />
                            5 DAY VIEW
                        </label>

Comment: Edit your question with the full code...

Answer (score 7):

Use a **change** event instead of a **click** event.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/mXLer/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on('change', '[type="radio"]', function(){ 
        alert('Change');
    });    
});
```

Comment: No downvote for this but the link and example are very vague (although accurate).  It just so happens that this is the first stackoverflow result that comes up from a google search on this topic.  Could be much better.